# Is it mandatory to isolate D+/D- to clean my noisy MIDI power supply

Tags: usb, audio, dc-dc-converter, midi, digital-isolator

I designed a Piano controller with MIDI synthesizer board which works pretty well but there's noise in the jack output. All my board is supplied by the USB (a typical type B connector).

I searched through internet and found out that it's due to the signal which is parasiting the power lines.
I also found some "USB isolators" on aliexpress and amazon and studied their design.

I want to integrate it to my PCB but I have few questions before beginning to draw the board :

I have to use a dcdc 5V isolated transformor but in all the projects that I studied there is always an ADuM4160 (or 3160). Which is a pretty expensive chip. Isn't it more a signal processing unit ? My signal is fine so is it mandatory to use this type of component ? Can't I just use a dcdc regulated isolator ? And finally do I need to use TVS ?

Also, is there any point in putting ferrite on the usb cable?

Here are some designs that I studied :

[ADUM3160 USB Isolator](https://oshwlab.com/wagiminator/adum3160-usb-isolator)
[DIY USB isolator](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/diy-usb-isolator.256280/)
[Classic isolator](https://fr.banggood.com/USB-Isolator-USB-to-USB-Optocoupler-Isolation-Module-Coupled-Protection-Board-ADUM3160-Isolation-Voltage-2500V-p-1454368.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: The USB data lines are referenced to ground so you can't isolate the power without isolating the data as well.

Comment: Hi, we will need to see a schematic and photo of the PCB to make accurate recommendations.  Please add these for the best answers.

Comment: The reason for the noise is unknown. Who knows if it is because of the power supplies of the other devices that connect to your MIDI synthesizer. You must think of the system as a whole. And if you need isolation, maybe it would be better to do it somewhere else than USB, like on audio output.

Comment: @Justme Using an aliexpress isolator decrease the noise, and we can hear when uploading things through USB. The Audio output is a jack, is there a way to isolate it ?

Comment: @ThibautBourgeais There is. You can buy audio isolators. But if the data transfer gives noise, we must see the schematics and PCB layout, instead of blindly going and isolating stuff, as contrary to your belief, isolation may not solve the problem of noise during data transfer. Show schematics, show PCB layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, the schmatics are patented. Finbarr is right I'll go find alternatives to ADuM3160

Comment: If you isolate the power connections you will end up with two grounds, one at either end of the cable. The data lines can't be referenced to both at the same time unless the grounds are connected, but then it's no longer isolated. Hence you need to isolate the data lines as well.

Comment: It appear obvious now. Thank you very much. I didn't really understand why the ADuM3160 was here.
I'll try to find a cheaper clone.

Comment: However, isolating the audio output is probably a much easier solution. Just use a small audio transformer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how it is possible to isolate the audio ? How the isolator detect what is a noise and what is sound ?

Comment: The problem we're all having is that it's not clear what you've got connected and why the isolation is needed to reduce noise. For starters, what's on the other end of the USB cable? Does the board connect to anything other than USB and audio output? Where is this 5V transformer connected?

Comment: I'm really sorry, here's a little scheme. I hope it'll explain better.

[img](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-_711_qngrCfRC--FcO0xHn-0lLKGb20/view?usp=sharing)

it's the brain of a MIDI keyboard